# nw.js. Запустить процесс. Command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Start() {
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("node -v", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        alert(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    alert(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    alert(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});}
```

В итоге команда "node" не найдена. :(
Делаю все это в nw.js (NodeWebkit)

Comment: а сама нода у вас стоит?

Comment: :)
Конечно!)
Ответ описан ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно указать полный путь до node.

```
function Start() {
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("/usr/local/bin/node -v", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        alert(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    alert(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    alert(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});}
```

Решение подходит только для OSX или MacOS. Причем если пользователь изменил стандартный путь Node.js при установке, то этот метод работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Указывайте полный путь для Node:

```
/path/to/node-webkit/nw
```